# Sharing Hazelcast Cluster across multiple development team

Tags: hazelcast

Read from a few places which indicate mapstore and maploader must be running with the Hazelcast Node. Would like to find out if there any ways to implement mapstore/maploader separate from the Hazelcast Node?

Background:
If i have a hazelcast cluster for the team, and this cluster is to be use by different sub-team providing different map as data, and each sub-team should implement mapstore/maploader for the map they own, how can this be done? (Note that each sub-team have their own SVN repository)

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0):

MapLoader's `load()` operation is only invoked on the node that would have the key when the key is missing, so there is no way to push this processing elsewhere.

However, each map can have a different MapStore/MapLoader implementation, so having a different team provide each is certainly feasible.

Exactly how you achieve this comes down to your build and deploy practices. For example, each team's classes could be in a separate jar file on the classpath. Or, there could be a single jar file constructed containing the classes provided by each team. Many ways exist!

Comment: There are mapstore config in hazelcast config file, does this means that for every new jar added, i will still need to manually update the config to indicate a mapstore for each newly added map? Is there a way to add mapstore config on runtime?

Comment: There are factory classes that could do this, but "_clever_" solutions with reflection tend to introduce a lot of technical debt. What problem really are you trying to solve ? Why should it be difficult to change the config file when a new Jar is added

Comment: Ownership of Hazelcast Cluster (Team A), Owner of Map 1 (Team B), Owner of Map 2 (Team C). Prod environment files and config cannot be changed easily. When Team C create a new map with new mapstore implementation, it should not incur changes for Team A which is the owner of every node.

Comment: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.3/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapStoreFactory.html is probably your best bet then.

Comment: Agree, will be trying out if this is possible. Thanks~

Comment: Thanks Neil~! I am thinking along another way, to have the hazelcast server app to include a folder into classpath, then using springboot configuration to retrieve database configuration to add in the config of using the mapstore. In this case, whenever there are addition of mapstore, will just need to add the database configuration, deploy the mapstore jar, then restart each node one by one.

Comment: my last idea work! However, it only works with spring configuration because thats the only way to define hazelcast config within code.